# Waiting for some time before executing the next segment of codes in python3.2

Tags: python, winapi, user-interface, python-3.x, pywin32

I am writing a code to run a gui application(winmerge) and then send some keystrokes to it. I need to wait for some time within the program till the GUI finishes running and then send some keystrokes to it to save the report. How do I implement this? `wait()` isn't working as after invoking it I can't send keys to the same window.

Answer (score 17):

```
from time import sleep
print "hi,"
sleep(5)
print "this is printed 5 seconds later"
```